# How to change the background color of corner cell in uicollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have to display corner cell with red color and rest of the cell with green color in UICollevtionView![image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add background color of specific index path in cellForItemAtindexPath

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YouCustomCellIdentifier",
                                                   for: indexPath)
    guard let checkMarkCell =  cell as? YouCustomCell else {
        return cell
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 0) { 
        cell.backgrouColor = UIColor.red
   } else {
        cell.backgrouColor = UIColor.green
    }
  return checkMarkCell
}
```